# Changing style of unknown element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a tic-tac-toe game where the user first clicks which player he wants to be, then clicks on the square in the board where he wants to play. The issue I'm having is changing the background of the square that the user clicks. Because I don't know which square the user will click, I can't figure out how to change the style of the background, because the square's id/class is unknown.

I can't say:

```
document.getElementById("randomId").style.backg    round
```

because I don't know which square the user will click. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe Game</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        #buttons{
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        #x{
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        #table{
            margin-top: 15px;
            background: gray;
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: auto;
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="buttons">
    <h2 id="h2">Choose your team!</h2>
    <button onclick="myFunctions()" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span
            style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 110%;">O</span></button>
    <button type="button" id="x" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </button>

    <table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
            <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
            <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
            <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
            <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
            <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
            <td onclick="myFunction()"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var master = false;
    var servant = false;

    function myFunctions(){
        master = true;

    }
    function myFunction() {
        if (master == true) {

        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any reason why you want to use javascript as opposed to jquery? i only ask this because boostrap's js needs jquery anyways

Comment: <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td> -> pass DOM element to function, this should help...

Comment: Yeah I just want to practice my JavaScript. And what do I put in the definition of the function? this.style.background?

Comment: You can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/0g5z47kn/

Comment: Use event delegation, and get the target with `event.target`.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could either do it like this, where you add an argument when you call the function, in this case the  `this` keyword would point to the html element (td).

By adding a css class, you can handle the changes relatively easily and check if it wasn't clicked before.

```js
var master = true;

// clickedElement = your dom element you want to update
function myFunction(clickedElement) {
  // if a dom element was given and it doesn't have a className yet
  if (clickedElement && !clickedElement.className) {
    // set a class on the element
    clickedElement.className = master ? 'master' : 'servant';

    // change the player (if it's not a master it's a servant)
    master = !master;
  }
}
```

```css
#buttons {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#x {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#table {
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: gray;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
.master {
  background-color: green;
}
.servant {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="buttons">
  <h2 id="h2">Choose your team!</h2>
  <button onclick="myFunctions()" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 110%;">O</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" id="x" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
  </button>

  <table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>
```

There is of course no reason to only store this information on the DOM, you would still have to evaluate if there were 3 cells of the same color. You might want to choose to keep a data structure that checks which block was clicked and who clicked it and if there are diagonally, vertically or horizontally 3 in a row for the person who just clicked.

and if you want some more inspiration, you can check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/oLyvwdph/)